# Зачем в функцию передавать переменные в качестве параметров, если они выдны по замыканию?

Tags: javascript

JS мой первый язык, по началу изучения было все логично и понятно, но через некоторое время, спустя сотни строк кода, я пришел к выводу, что не понимаю базовых вещей,хотя уже понимаю более сложные. Собственно вопрос:
Например, есть простая функция сложения чисел,в которую мы передаем 2 числа введенных пользователем:

```
window.onload = function(){
const x = +prompt("Введи x","");
const y = +prompt("Введи y","");
function sum(num1,num2){
return num1 + num2;
}
console.log(sum(x,y));
}
```

Все работает, все понятно.
Но зачем передавать параметры, если функция sum() и так видит переменные x,y за счет замыкания и без проблем с ними работает?

```
window.onload = function(){
const x = +prompt("Введи x","");
const y = +prompt("Введи y","");
function sum(){
return x + y;
}
console.log(sum());
}
```

Результат тот же. В чем тогда разница, объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: правила этикета видимо?)) это же в целом не очень умно вызывать функцию `sum` без аргументов....ведь она должна что-то складывать.....да и вообще в функцию принято передавать аргументы.. а не из глобальной области тянуть...имхо...............также можно будет, если захочется, просто взять эту функцию и вынести куда-то ещё......а если ничего не передавать и переносить куда-либо - всё сломается..........это моё мнение только)

Comment: Может из соображений универсальности?) Чтоб можно было использовать не только для сложения `x` и `y`, но и чтоб можно было аналогичные операции через нее прогонять с другими переменными. Так то можно и без функции обойтись и написать просто `console.log( x + y );` и получить тот же результат, да еще и короче будет

Comment: Если вынести функцию sum за пределы window.onload, то второй вариант станет не рабочим. Попробуй, сразу будет видна разница. В первом случае функция sum не зависит от внешних данных и работает только с переданными ей аргументами. Такой подход является предпочтительным, т.к. повышает читаемость кода - не нужно искать, где же объявлены внешние переменные, и кто с ними еще работает.

Comment: Еще можно представить ситуацию, когда надо посчитать три суммы подряд. Получается, перед каждым вызовом sum нужно менять значения внешних переменных x и y, что непрактично. Не говоря уже о том, что x и y могут быть задействованы где-то еще, а значения были изменены. Функция должна быть самодостаточна.

Answer (score 1):

Первое, что нужно принять, изучая Js, - что это язык достаточно свободный. В нем ты можешь делать одну задачу разными вариантами. И при этом любой из этих вариантов будет рабочий. То есть твой вопрос сейчас, если абстрагироваться от программирования, выглядит так. У меня две кувалды, одна синяя, другая белая. Почему я должен бить именно белой? Ответ: Ты можешь бить любой кувалдой, какой пожелаешь сам.

Но вернемся в Js. Почему способ без передачи параметров в функцию может оказаться в каких то историях хуже, чем тот, в котором передают. Представь себе, что у тебя программа стала на 10000 строк, и если у тебя переменные передаются в функцию. То читая такой код, ты сразу понимаешь, что о! в эту функцию передаются переменные. А если этого не происходит, то ты можешь с трудом найти потом, откуда вообще они взялись.

Также когда ты добреешься до более глубокого изучения области видимости переменных, то не всегда у тебя получится как в твоем примере получить переменные, не передовая их через функцию.

Примерно так в общих чертах можно ответить на твой вопрос.